How can I download the current tab url from a chrome extension service worker if the current tab is a pdf?
So I'm building a Chrome extension using Kotlin JS that will create a context menu button that will allow users to import the contents of the current tab into the extension and do useful things with it. If you're interested in what those useful things are you can see a non functional v0.1 of it here or checkout the website.
I have it mostly working but it fails when a pdf is open in the current tab. A minimal working example that reproduces the issue is below
import app.externals.chrome.contextMenus.OnClickData
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.client.statement.readBytes
import js.objects.jso
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

private val client = HttpClient()

private suspend fun downloadPage(onClickData: OnClickData): ByteArray? {
    return onClickData.frameUrl?.let { client.get(it).readBytes() }
}

fun main() {
    app.externals.chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener {
        externals.chrome.contextMenus.create(jso {
            this.id = "download-page"
            this.title = "download-page"
            this.contexts = arrayOf("all")
        })
    }

    app.externals.chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener { onClickData, _ ->
        if (onClickData.menuItemId == "download-page") {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                downloadPage(onClickData)
            }
        }
    }
}

When the "download-page" context menu button is clicked it will get the url of the current tab and download its contents. This works fine for most sites, but if I try it on a pdf document like this one I get a CORS error
Access to fetch at 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf' from origin 'chrome-extension://bdicfcohaofoaoakidlocbdaphldiaok' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. 

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that Chrome views pdf documents in iframes through what's basically an embedded application. I want to resolve this issue and have the service worker successfully download the pdf.
I made some progress in an unexpected way. If I define a blank content script and have the manifest run it for pdf urls it magically works.
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "The Grok App",
  "description": "Search For Your Documents",
  "version": "0.2.0",

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "logo_no_text128.png"
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "logo_no_text16.png",
    "48": "logo_no_text48.png",
    "64": "logo_no_text64.png",
    "128": "logo_no_text128.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "chromeExtensionBackground.js"
  },

  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidePanel.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*.pdf"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus",
    "scripting",
    "sidePanel"
  ]
}

Here content.js is totally blank and does nothing. I don't totally understand why this works, but it seems to fix the problem, which would be fine but I'm not sure the Chrome extension reviewers will be okay with me running a blank js file on all pdf files as a work around for what really seems like a bug. So any other solutions would be appreciated!

Yes, it's a bug in Chrome: activeTab doesn't work with pdf because it's shown in an iframe. The content_scripts implicitly adds host permissions, so it's a valid workaround, which is better than adding host_permissions because those cannot be limited by a path pattern to just pdf. You can add a comment about it inside content.js.
